# What is the submitter button on Reddit?

Tags: reddit

The `[S]` button in the image below is labeled as `submitter`

[image: snippet of screen shot]

What does it do? I click on it but nothing happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this help page](http://www.reddit.com/r/help/comments/vkxme/what_does_s_mean_next_to_my_username/) for "what is submitter reddit next to my name".

The **[S]** indicates that I'm the original poster, the one who started the page/link discussion, equivalent to having my name highlighted on Stack Exchange.

A comment of V2Blast:

> In general, if you see an "S", "F", "M", "A", or "Δ" (delta), you can hover over it to see what it means.
>
> (In order, those are "submitter", "friend" (you can add them as a friend from their userpage to more quickly recognize their posts), "moderator", "admin", and "admin emeritus" (former admin).)